# Can i use CiviToken in Custom Fields

Tags: custom-fields, tokens

Can i use CiviToken (https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken) as Default Values in CiviCRM Custom Fields the same way Drupal lets you use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible. The tokens in CiviCRM are used in letters/emails. So they are used for communication with the contacts in your database.

Also note that a token in CiviCRM is always related to a contact.